# Bandwidth calculation by JW Player in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jwplayer

I'm using [this JW Player wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/other_notes/) on my website to play the videos.

I want to calculate the total bandwidth consumed by each user on my website. there will be users who will watch the complete video and some will not watch the complete video, in both cases there will be difference in the bandwidth used by each user.

- Can this bandwidth , in both of the scenarios be calculated?
- Is there any PHP/Wordpress plugin available or any script that can calculate this bandwidth?

If there isn't any then please explain this a bit so that I can write my own.

Thank You !

Comment: maybe you should start with http logs, I don't think wordpress is capable to capture "video" plays.

Comment: Yeah, WP doesn't capture this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as the commenters stated, this probably is more of a server issue than a wordpress one. That being said, you could get a partial view on your user behaviour by adding the username to the analytics portion of a page. I know Piwik can do this, and also Google Analytics.

Then at least you know which users watch your video's the most, but unfortunately not if they watch the whole video.

You could also include a call to the analytics package after a user finished watching the video, using the JWplayer API. Then you've got the ratio partly/entirely watched movies, and from there on you can do some approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Got help from the JwPlayer [API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming)  and this worked for me.